# git checkout deletes files

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am new to git and I wanted to try the branch feature. I am working with a local repository. The problem is that if I create a new branch and then go back to the master branch, some files are lost.

This is what I do:

I have two directories:

```
$ ls
g_LT  LT
```

and a source code file lt_mp2.F in the LT directory:

```
$ ls LT/ | grep lt_mp2.F
lt_mp2.F
```

The other directory contains a relative symlink to this file:

```
$ ls -l g_LT/ | grep lt_mp2.F
lt_mp2.F -> ../LT/lt_mp2.F
```

Both files are lost if I create a new branch and then go back to the master branch. So, let me show this:

Before I create the new branch, let's check that there is nothing to commit:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached from 2617e8a
nothing to commit, working directory clean here
```

Let's also check that we are in the master branch and that the last commit is from Oct 13 2016

```
$ git branch -a
* (detached from 2617e8a)
master

$ git log
commit 3484261bdd585671bf7c74568542a62610c2deaf
Author: [...]
Date:   Thu Oct 13 09:25:06 2016 +0200
[...]
```

Now I create a new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b testbranch
Switched to a new branch 'testbranch'
```

The source files are still there:

```
$ ls LT/ | grep lt_mp2.F
lt_mp2.F
$ ls -l g_LT/ | grep lt_mp2.F
lt_mp2.F -> ../LT/lt_mp2.F
```

Now I go back to the master branch:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

**But now the source files are gone:**

```
$ ls LT/ | grep lt_mp2.F
(no output)
$ ls -l g_LT/ | grep lt_mp2.F
(no output)
```

**Moreover the last commit is suddenly from Dec 2015 instead of Oct 13 2016:**

```
$ git log
commit 634741172ed34cd687fd91f14da45004b3328f8b
Author: [...]
Date:   Tue Dec 1 18:54:57 2015 +0100
[...]
```

What is happening here and why am I losing my source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not (losing any files, nor any commits).

This part of your starting claim is wrong:

> Let's also check that we are in the master branch [snip]
>
> ```
> $ git branch -a
> * (detached from 2617e8a)
> master
> ```

This shows that you are *not* on branch `master` at the start.  Instead, you have a "detached HEAD".  The most recent explicit `git checkout` of a raw hash ID, or equivalent—such as a tag name, or a remote-tracking branch name—checked out commit `2617e8a`.  Your `git log` output shows that the current commit is probably<sup>1</sup> `3484261bdd585671bf7c74568542a62610c2deaf`, and the "detached from" wording suggests that you probably made this commit yourself (Git uses "detached at" when you have not moved HEAD, and "detached from" when you have).

The `git log` command defaults to showing commits starting from your current (`HEAD`) commit<sup>2</sup> and working backwards.  This is true whether HEAD is "detached" or not.  (A non-detached HEAD is a HEAD that refers to a branch name, such as `master`.  Running `git checkout branchname` gives you a non-detached HEAD, i.e., HEAD now points to *branchname*, so that commits are found using the named branch.)

If you want to see more or other commits, you can tell `git log` to start somewhere else.  Wherever you tell it to start, it works backwards from there.

Thus, this just means that `master`, the branch name, points to a commit from back in 2015.  Once `HEAD` points to `master`, `git log` (with no additional arguments) starts with its most recent commit and works backwards from there.

Presumably if `master` is that out of date, all the real work has been happening on some other branch(es).

The files disappear when you switch from `3484261...` to `6347411...` (this is probably the commit identified by `master`) because they *are* in the former commit and *are not* in the latter.  So Git removes them from the index and work-tree when switching commits.  Switching back to `3484261...` (by checking it out by ID, or by the new name you gave it) will put them back into the index and work-tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git log` sorts its output by date, by default, showing commits with later dates first.  This code changed somewhat at some point that I missed, because it used to be possible to "post-date" a commit into 2038 or so, so that it was always shown at the top of `git log` output, if it was to be shown at all.  This had stopped working when I tested it recently.

<sup>2</sup>See footnote 1, and note that you can change the sort order, and/or constrain it, e.g., with `--topo-order`.  Adding `--graph` sets `--topo-order`.  Usually, commits' dates are more or less in line with their graph topology, so that these flags do not make huge changes in sorting order.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. But how can I resolve this "detached HEAD" thing? As far as I can remember I started using git with "git init" and then I always just used "git add -A" and "git commit -a".

Comment: I don't know exactly how you got the detached HEAD in the first place.  Git records a lot of useful information in "reflogs" (there's one for each branch, and one more for `HEAD` itself), but reflog entries expire after a while: 30 days for some, 90 for others, by default.  Since it looks like your `master` was last touched almost a year ago, the traces in the HEAD reflog are likely long gone. [continued]

Comment: As long as you can *find* the commits, though, all you have to do is give them a name, such as a branch name. You did this with `git checkout -b testbranch`. If you run `git log testbranch` you will see those commits. With `git log --branches`, you will see all commits reachable from all branches, which at this point is just `master` and `testbranch`. Using `git log master testbranch`will thus do the same thing. Using `--all` gets all references (mainly branches and tags). Add `--oneline --decorate --graph` to your `git log` to get a graph drawing with labels (or try a GUI—I usually hate GUIs)

Comment: (... but they *are* useful for drawing pretty graphs.)

Comment: Ok, and what about merging testbranch with master? Would result in a single master branch that I desire?

Comment: It's not possible to tell without viewing the graph, or some part of it at least.  Merging is all about *combining* two *different* sets of changes: those from the merge base to one branch tip, and those from the merge base to the other branch tip. But what is the merge base? *That* is determined by the graph.